# Как скрывать блок div в зависимости от разрешения экрана?

Tags: html, javascript, css

Для разных разрешений экрана - своя структура сайта. В десктоп-версии все div'ы показывать (грубо говоря). В мобильной - кое-что хотелось бы убрать. Как это реализовать?

У меня такие догадки:

1. Получаем разрешение экрана и подгружаем нужный css. (В mobil.css - `display:none`.)
2. Не подгружая другие css, люди как-то используют js для скрытия div. Что за способ такой и как это через js делается? Можно ли это сделать без js (слышал, что в старых мобилах js плохо работает). А без js  и одним css файлом это можно реализовать или это невозможно?

Буду рад любому совету! Спасибо!

Comment: @import url() [device]

Comment: А можно и воспользоваться css media-queries, как это описано на [ruseller](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=2&id=698).

Comment: Конечно в старых мобильниках не пойдет но как вариант воспользоваться ccs3 @media [Описание](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-media-queries) [Спецификация](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/)

Comment: `@media` как вариант. На чистом CSS. Задаешь размер экрана, при котором будет срабатывать `display: none;` и все.

Comment: пишится `@media screen and (max-width:350px){.text{display:none;}}` и всё

Comment: @Geyan стоило опубликовать ответ )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как вариант, с использованием `javascript`

```
<style>
    body.mobile .no-mobile { display: none; }
</style>
<body>
    ...
    <div class="no-mobile">
       ...
    </div>
    ...
    <script>
        if(window.innerWidth < 800) {
            var body = (document.getElementByTagName("body"))[0];
            body.className = "mobile";
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: спасибо! но что-то не выходит.
<style>
body.mobile .no-mobile{ display: none;}
.glavn{display:block; width:60%; border:1px solid #000000;}
.no-mobile{display:block; width:30%; border:1px solid #000000;} 
</style>
<body>
<div class="glavn">Видится везде</div>
<div class="no-mobile">Исчезает при мобайл</div>

<script>
        if(window.innerWidth < 800) {
            var body = (document.getElementByTagName("body"))[0];
            body.className = "mobile";
        }
</script>
</body>

Comment: использовать для таких целей JS не есть хорошо, используйте уже заложенные @media queries в CSS тем самым снимите лишнюю нагрузку на браузер.

Answer (score 5):

Для решения подобных проблем в CSS есть свойство `@media`:

```
@media screen and (max-width:350px) {
    .object {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Без javascript не обойтись!

Пример для раздумий:

```
<script>
    if(window.innerWidth < 800)
    {
        var divS = new Array("id_2", "id_4");
        alert("div'ы " + divS + " не показываются");
    }
</script>

<div id="id_1">ID 1</div>
<div id="id_2">ID 2</div>
<div id="id_3">ID 3</div>
<div id="id_4">ID 4</div>
<div id="id_5">ID 5</div>
```

З.Ы. **Пример**!

Comment: Спасибо, Palmervan! Буду думать)

Comment: а `\@media` handheld не проканает?

Comment: Должно проканать)

Comment: Без javascript не обойтись! - обойтись медиа запросами.

Comment: @user190134, в 12 году их поддержка была не очень